# Impersonate gCal user from service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

Looks like late last year, Google changed behavior of calendar API in not allowing service accounts to create calendar events with attendees.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1725

https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/16769831?hl=en

So, to create event with attendees one has to ensure that domain-wide delegation is setup for the service account, and then specify the target/delegate account for the calendar the service account is attempting to write events to.  I've done the former, and the latter I have the following code...

```
const jwt = jsonwebtoken.sign({
    iss: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
    scope: SCOPES,
    aud: 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token',
    iat: currentUnixTimeInSeconds,
    exp: currentUnixTimeInSeconds + 3600,
    sub: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_TARGET_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
  },
  privateKey,
  {
    algorithm: 'RS256',
    header: {
      alg: 'RS256',
      typ: 'JWT',
    },
  }
);
```

...and then call https://oauth2.googleapis.com to get a bearer token, but it always errors out.  ( with "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check. The right audience is..." following by what looks to be a long bearer token URL"

https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=...

)

What is the right way to do impersonation with service accounts against the Google calendar API?

Comment: do you have an error you would like us to help with im not sure i understand the issue here.    please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The error is pretty straightfoward - it's "Invalid JWT: Failed audience check", and the issue I'm asking for help with is how does/should one do targeted delegation (so can add attendees to gCal events) from a service account.  I'm not finding any docs/examples, and the current approach, above, based on this guidance below, doesn't seem to work

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [Domain Wide Delegation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) and the whole procedure is very detailed in this [documentation page](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests). Is much more simpler and safer to use the correct library than actually making  yourself all the requests.

From the [own google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#authorizingrequests) on how to achieve this through HTTP requests:

> **Recommendation:** Although your application can complete these tasks by directly interacting with the OAuth 2.0 system using HTTP, the mechanics of server-to-server authentication interactions require applications to create and cryptographically sign JSON Web Tokens (JWTs), and it's easy to make serious errors that can have a severe impact on the security of your application.
>
> For this reason, **we strongly encourage you to use libraries**, such as the Google APIs client libraries, that **abstract the cryptography** away from your application code.